# Connect two diferent tables and edit php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I cannot resolve this problem. In database are 2 diferent tables, 1 TABLES called USERS second is TICKETS. When user registered that information is stored into USERS table, only registered users is aloved to open ticket for support. When user open ticket that information is stored into TICKETS table. Now problem is when some random user want to see tickets status, they display all tickets stored into TICKET table and that is what we don't want, we want to display only ticket status from that user who is logged in. Code example below:

On ticket-status.php page code for preview data is:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets JOIN users WHERE users.email=tickets.email");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr>
<th scope="row"><?php echo $row['ticket_id'] ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $row['item_selected'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['help_selected'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['message'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is how look users database:

```
ID - FIRST NAME - LAST NAME - EMAIL - PASSWORD - PHONE - CREATED - MODIFIED
1     Greg         McFe       u@g.com   123       123     date      date
2     Roy          McDs       a@g.com   133       222     date      date
3     Tina         MCda       g@g.com   333       111     date      date
```

Database for tickets is:

```
TICKET_ID - ITEM_SELECTED - HELP_SELECTED - EMAIL - PHONE - MESSAGE - STATUS
   1             theme2         problem     u@g.com   123    msg1      open
   2             theme12        errors      a@g.com   222    msg12     open
   3             theme8         solution    g@g.com   333    msg9      closed
```

What i need. On ticket-status.php page when random user logged in and go to see his ticket status, display his open ticket. Example:

```
TICKET ID - ITEM SELECTED - HELP SELECTED - MESSAGE - STATUS
   2        theme12          errors       msg12       open
```

Comment: Have you tried also checking the phone? It might be possible that more than one user might use the same email address.

Comment: You miss the where clause`SELECT * FROM tickets JOIN users WHERE users.email=tickets.email where user.email='<users mail address>'`. BTW, you should store the user id in ticket not the email

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Also the phone number can be used ab many peoples

Comment: @Jens ?? 2 `WHERE` clauses, I think you mean `AND`

Comment: I get whole table displayed or i don't get anything. Can you explain me more about that store user id into tickets table. @Jens

Comment: @mcstudent a record in a table is unambiguously identified by is id, so you can use it to reference this record in other tables

Comment: Can you write and example to try that code? @Jens

Comment: @mcstudent it is not the code it is the db design

Comment: 'When user open ticket that information is stored into TICKETS table' - You decided to store the user email address in tickets table which is fine as long as the email address column is declared as unique. Such that you will be selecting from tickets based on email address. The other alternative is storing but the users' user table id as Jens suggested.

Comment: How to store user_id into ticket table to try that option? @RiggsFolly

Comment: You just told @RiggsFolly that you have a Login. So, when a user is logged in, you just need to get the user users table id and save it in a session variable. You will then be able to insert in tickets table or use it for other reasons. I like to improve on my last point - if a user can buy more than one ticket then only the users table email address column should be unique. The tickets's should not.

Comment: Okay so table of tickets just need to have user_id, item_selected, help_selected, message and status? @hans-afrik

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes you are right

Comment: How to insert user id to tickets status from logged in session? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Do you save something in the session to uniquely identify the currently logged in user?

Comment: I create working code. Thanks i work 20h on this without stoping my brain has slowed a little. @RiggsFolly

Comment: 'Okay so table of tickets just need to have user_id....' - That's an option. Which requires just changing the email column to user_id. 20h of working without stopping is not good. You need to give yourself always some breaks. At times your solution comes when you are on break.

Comment: Look i created tickets base from scrach and base look like this `ID--ITEM_SELECTED--HELP_SELECTED--MESSAGE--STATUS` and when user (me) log in and open ticket i generate to store user id from login session. But i can't display only ticket from logged in user, i display all registered users who opened tickets. How to display only user by id. If u want i can put now code into answer to see how its look like.

Answer (score 5):

You need to limit the results to only the logged in user by adding that to your `WHERE` clause.

I dont see from your code that you know what the EMAIL of the logged in user is, but I assume you must know this somehow

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets 
    JOIN users ON users.EMAIL = tickets.EMAIL
WHERE user.EMAIL = <the logged in users EMAIL>
```

> It would have been a better idea to have put the `ID` of the users into the `Tickets` table, rather than the `EMAIL` for many reasons. Not least of which is that people change their EMAIL, and if they do you woudl only have had to amend the `users` table and all would have continued working. As it is now, you would need to modify all their `Tickets` as well.

Comment: Have u try that code? And did it work for you? How to sepcified logged in user email, if u have 100 users with random emails?

Comment: Where do you keep information about the logged in user?

Comment: Can you write working code because i try every single posible solution and didnt work. If i need to edit my sql table i will edit just tell me where is problem and what solution will fix that problem. Thanks

Comment: Registered users info is into users table, ticket info is into tickets table

Comment: Yes but when user logs in, how do you remember which user is logged in while they are logged in

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: If you cannot get the code to remember who is logged in, by using something like the SESSION then there is no way to limit the query to Just The LoggedIn User

Comment: I do not think we understand each other, can you send me a private message to send you the entire code. I think u will see where is problem.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to send private messages.

Comment: Please dont be offended, but it seems to me from this and your other questions that you have started this project without the necessary basic knowledge and tools. Can I suggest you get a beginners PHP development book or find some basic PHP Development tutorials on the net. SO is not really supposed to be a Beginners Tutorial Site

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to limit it to that particular user's tickets:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets JOIN users WHERE users.email=tickets.email AND users.phone=tickets.phone AND users.id=?");
$result->bind_param('i', $id);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: You need to set the `$id` variable.

Comment: I think this is one of the OP's problems. OP has not saved the logged in users info anywhere when the user logs in, session for example so has no way of knowing who logged in and therefore no way of adding a value in the bind